# Which library contains \left(?

Tags: math-mode

I have included libraries amsthm, amsmath, amssymb, mathtools and hyperref and I get an error when I use `\left(` or `\right)`.

However, it doesn't happen in overleaf, which also includes graphicx, multicol and array.

So, my question is which library contains the `\left(` command ?

Comment: It will be easier to help if you post a minimal code demonstrating what happens.

Comment: If you use one *or* the other, you'll get errors yes, because you always have to have *both*. If you only need e.g. `\left\{`, then add `\right.`, the period indicates an invisible/empty delimiter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a library what is causing you trouble.

If you include `\left(` also a `\right)` (or a `\right.`, or maybe mathematically senseless, but also `\right], \right|,` etc. would work) should be included in the same equation line, and vice versa. If you jump a line in, say, `align`-environment you would get an error.

```
\begin{align}
X&=\left( \sum  \mbox{something} 
\\
&+\mbox{more stuff} \right)
\end{align}
```

and

```
\begin{align}
Y& =\left( \sum  &  \mbox{something} \right)
\end{align}
```

both give you an error, whereas

```
\begin{align}
X&=\left( \sum  \mbox{something} \right.
\\
&\left.+\mbox{more stuff} \right)
\end{align}
```

and

```
\begin{align}
Y& =\left(  \sum \right. & \left. \vphantom{\sum} \mbox{something} \right)
\end{align}
```

don't. Alternatively, you can get rid of this problem by using

```
 \big(, \bigg(, \Big(,...
```

instead.

Comment: Yes ! I was doing it in align environment. How can I solve this ?

Comment: I need the left and right brackets. Otherwise, it's too small.

Comment: @user230452 See the edit. Otherwise, use `\big(` or `\Big(`, which doesn't cause error.

Comment: Might be better to promote the left and right versions of `\big` and friends. Usually it does not matter, but some times it does and you can see the difference.

Comment: Other than that, the general rule is avoid `\left...\right` constructions for the most part. Often they produce undesirable results, or as in this case, does not work.

Comment: @daleif Ok. I didn't know this. Your method is to write \right. at the end, and \left. at the beginning of every line ? Can you explain exactly you did different ?

Comment: Thanks. Both big and Big didn't give me an error. But, big was too small and Big did the job perfectly ! How did you immediately identify the problem and know how to rectify it ? Do you have a lot of experience with LaTeX ? Also, how do you know subtle things like \left \right shouldn't be on the same line ? Is there some rule for this or is it just trial and error ?

Comment: @user230452 there is still `\bigg`

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, but what helped me the most was your comment to use Big. Put that in the answer.

Comment: @user230452 there is `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg` and `\Bigg` with recommended `\Xl` and `\Xr` variants. Which sizes to choose depends on the situation and taste. My general rule is: (1) I should be obvious to the user what is being fenced in, but (2) the fences should not be scaled to such an extend they take focus from the equation

Comment: @daleif What is the reason that \left ... \right constructions don't work across lines ?

Comment: @user230452 because it is essentially a very special type of construction, and as with `\macro{ .... }` you get an error if the `}` is missing, you can see the `\right)` part in the same way.

Comment: Another limitation is what exactly are we scaling for if we have `\left( ... \\ ... \right)`, are we just ignoring the ``\\``? Plus, now the ``\\`` is hidden inside a macro where `align` has no way of finding it.

Comment: @daleif  Also, tell me one more thing. Does Math mode work inside Intertext ?

Comment: @user230452 have you tried?

Comment: @daleif I tried but I didn't compile it. I noticed the dollar signs weren't coloured like they usually are. So, I just closed Intertext and started again. I don't know if it would have given an error.

Comment: `\intertext{via $x>0$ we have}` works fine, otherwise post a MWE in a new question